# What does running slice() on an array do?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

From underscore:

```
  // Create a (shallow-cloned) duplicate of an object.
  _.clone = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    return _.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : _.extend({}, obj);
  };
```

If an array is detected, the dev does a

```
obj.slice()
```

I ran this in the console:

```
[0,1,2,3].slice()
```

and it appeared to do nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: essentially, it creates a shallow copy of the array

Comment: `var test = [0,1,2,[0,1,2,3]].slice()` - still it appears to do nothing.

Comment: take a look at the result.

Comment: `var arr = [1, 2, 3]; arr !== arr.slice();`

Comment: I can still do `test[3][1]` after the shallow copy which make the copy appear deep to me.

Comment: @Daniel - I know, its the same array in two different memory locations, the equality operator is testing the reference.

Comment: its not the same array however.

Comment: I think you have a misconception if what shallow and deep copying means. `var orig = [obj1, obj2];` Shallow copy: `shallow(orig) !== orig && shallow(orig)[0] === orig[0]`. Deep copy: `deep(orig) !== orig && deep(orig)[0] !== orig[0]`. So basically, shallow copying only creates a copy of the container, but not its contents. Deep copying also creates a copy of its contents.

Comment: it's not the same whole array in both, but the sub array is the same in both.

Answer (score 4):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

When you provide no parameters, slice will start at index 0 and go to the end, this giving the impression that it's doing nothing.

> What am I missing?

Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to manipulate a part of the array. If you did `[0,1,2,3].slice(2)`, you could get "2, 3".  As Kodlee's answer says, you're missing the "slice" you want that you'd pass in as a parameter.

Comment: `[0,1,2,3].slice(2)` returns `[2, 3]`. `.slice()` without argument is most often used to create a *shallow copy* of the array.